# Javascript speech synthesis English with French words

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

Reading out medical texts we come across special terms which need some nudging. Take for example, "Guillain-Barré syndrome":

```
window.speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Guillain-Barré syndrome"))
```

it seems like the accented "é" isn't even attempted to be spoken.

Is this a known problem with known work-arounds? Is there some sort of phonetic alphabet or escape expressions that could be used to guide the voice synthesizer? I remember in the old days of the Commodore 64, there was the voice synthesizer called "Sam", and it could be given phonetic escape sequences, and also pitch and emphasis could be controlled by the input string, even allowing it to sing (the Star Spangled Banner as it were.)

What kind of strategies are available in SpeechSynthesisUtterance object?

I have tried to use the sort of phonetic spelling which certain lay medical dictionaries provide, e.g. [gee-YAH-buh-RAY](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/guillain-barre-syndrome/symptoms-causes/syc-20362793), but that doesn't come out right.